# My nuxt redirects depending on where you are in the web site

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

This is an example:

I have a header, with some links, one of them has the url: "/aig-en"

But, if I go to my "personal data" section when I am logged in, which is a different place than the "/" of my project, the path from before becomes /user/aig-es.

Im using Nuxt 2.15.7

I have searched for documentation, github issues, forums but I can't find anything similar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.